# Maven Configuration

Tags: java, maven

Failure to transfer org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:2.0.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): No response received after 60000

Comment: Just delete local repository and restart your build.And it looks like you have some problems with your internet connection.

Comment: What did you do to get the error? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: try `mvn clean install -U`. It will download libraries regardless what you have in cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are steps which you can follow.

1. Make sure internet is ON.
2. Delete {user.home}/.m2 directory.
3. Run `mvn clean install`

Above will build your artifact from scratch. Following command will help you converting the artifact in eclipse runnable project

4. mvn `eclipse:eclipse`

Cheers
Anant

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to upload/download artifact to repo. You need to contact your SCM/maven repo administrator. Server may be down and that is why you are not able to upload/download your artifact.